# Llamar a función desde Html en node JS con evento onclik()

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

tengo una aplicación realizada con node js y express js, y quiero llamar a una función desde el Frontend con un boton que lance un evento onclick(). La cuestión es que no me detecta el archivo en el que se encuentra la funcion (index.js/Main()). La app es un poco compleja ya que utiliza Handerlbars para mostrar las vistas y tiene controladores asociados.

La vista estado.hbs, desde donde hago el evento es esta:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<script type="script" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid col-6 mh-100 mt-5">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="background1 col-1">
                <div id="box-out1">
                    <div id="box-inside1">
                        <div id="circulo1" class="color1"></div>
                        <div id="circulo2" class="color2"></div>
                        <div id="circulo3" class="color3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="col-6 mt-5">
                <button id="buton" class="btn btn-ligh" onclick="Main()">Iniciar servicio</button>
                <button class=" btn btn-light">Detener servicio</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Mientras que La estructura de archivos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí estaría el archivo index.js:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado añadir el script a la vista, pero tampoco me reconoce el archivo. Y creo que estoy utilizando funciones de la parte cliente para acceder al servidor.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente estas llamando al index incorrecto.

El servidor crea una carpeta para que puedas utilizar ciertas utilidades desde tu front, y esta es de la carpeta public.

Debes recordar que una vez que estas en el cliente (Maquina cliente), no puedes acceder a recursos del servidor, a menos que sea por una api.
Sin embargo se entregan ciertos recursos como la carpeta public, donde puedes alojar codigo javascript o css en esta carpeta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veo tu código, buscará dentro de la carpeta public el archivo **index.js**, y no irá a la raiz del proyecto a buscar tu otro **index.js**

Comment: Entiendo... por ejemplo, para encender un modulo no me sirve esta forma no?
Es decir, que el usuario pulse un boton y de inicie tal función? Gracias

Comment: Dentro de tu carpeta public, crea un archivo con el nombre index.js alli podrás invocarlo desde el navegador, pero solo funciones desde navegador.